# MySQL Joining Results of Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find rows if the second query that do not exist in the first.  But I get the 'You have error in your SQL syntax near a right join' error.

```
(SELECT t1.id AS id, t2.id, t3.id
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
) a
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT id
FROM table4 
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IN (1, 2)) b 
ON a.id = b.id
```

What do I do wrong in this query?  Thank you.

Comment: You may want to add a `SELECT * FROM` at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In join queries, you must put all your columns in the first select statement.  The second select statement in your query is invalid.

```
SELECT 
  t1.id as id, t2.id, t3.id, b.id 
FROM 
   (table1 t1 
 inner join table2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id
 inner join table3 t3 on t3.id=t2.id)
 right join table4 b on t1.id = b.id
WHERE b.col1 IS NOT NULL AND b.col2 IN (1, 2))
```